# Use ArrayList to get value without using zero as first value - Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, indexing

I need to fix this.. It is calling an array number, although it does the next value in the array because the first one is zero.

I am using ArrayList. Is there a way to call for the index value - 1 perhaps ?

Here is an example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) 
{
    output.write(String.valueOf(page_words.get(questions.get(i-1))));
    System.out.println(page_words.get(questions.get(i)));
}
```

See the i-1, is there another way to this that actually works?

Comment: First of all, does this even compile?  I think the index of -1 probably doesn't exist.  Second, if you just want to iterate through all values, replace `output.write(String.valueOf(page_words.get(questions.get(i-1))));` with `output.write(String.valueOf(page_words.get(questions.get(i))));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't it will generate `Exception`.

[arrayList.get(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method of array list can take argument `>=0 and<size()` So for ***Negative value*** it will generate `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So for `ArrayListindex < 0` or `ArrayListindex >= size()` `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be generated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>= 0` and `< size()`?

Comment: im using that as an example of what I want to do, use like the value of the number before i, because of the 0

Comment: well you should not use get method with -1 as i have said but you can use variable with value -1 and use ++i to get 0th element.

Comment: @user3596380 if you want to get the one before i, then what do you want to do if i is 0?